# Linear Independent Eigenvectors and Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I did the following question:

> Show that if $A$ is a square matrix and $A^n = I$, the identity matrix, for some $n>0$, then $A$ has a basis of eigenvectors.

The solution actually shows that A has no generalized eigenvectors that are not genuine/ordinary eigenvectors. That is, $A$ only has "ordinary" eigenvectors. But I don't understand why showing this can conclude that $A$ has a basis of eigenvectors?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$, then since $A^n-I=0$, we see $p(x)|(x^n-1)$. Since $x^n-1$ has no repeated root, we see $p(x)$ also has no repeated root. Then there is a theorem saying that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated root, which is our case.

For your information, this is the theorem in Linear Algebra, *Hoffman and Kunze*, Page 204.